# Any idea why my dropdown isn't working in Bootstrap5?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm following a tutorial on Udemy and we've been asked to create a navbar, however the tutorial is in Bootstrap4 and I obviously want to be learning Bootstrap5, so I'm not sure how else I change the code to make it work apart from ml-auto to ms-auto and data-target to data-bs-target etc...

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">

    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data--bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed.. I'm stupid :D I had data--bs-target rather than data-bs-target

Answer (score 0):

data--bs-target

you added a double dash and add a closing tag for section.

Answer (score 0):

In  tag, there is "data--bs-target" attribute. There should be "data-bs-target" with single hyphen after "data".

P.S. Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your HEAD tag to get better results in mobile version.